# How to create a singleton pattern of the following class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class to create object context. To manage object creation, I want to use singleton pattern. How to create following class object creation pattern as singleton in C# ?

```
  public abstract class EFContextBase<TContext> : IDisposable where TContext : ObjectContext, new()
        {
            private TContext _dataContext;
                protected virtual TContext DataContext
            {
                get
                {
                    if ((object)this._dataContext == null)
                        this._dataContext = Activator.CreateInstance<TContext>();
                    return this._dataContext;
                }
            }

  public EFContextBase()
            {
                this.DataContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            }
                public void Dispose()
            {
                this.Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize((object)this);
            }
                private void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!disposing || (object)this._dataContext == null)
                    return;
                this._dataContext.Dispose();
                this._dataContext = default(TContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would this be different than any other singleton you'd create?

Comment: No answer, just a remark: you gave TContext the new() constraint, but you use Activator to create an instance.

Comment: EFContextBase should have a local flag indication for disposed as a best practice, to avoid multiple disposes.

Comment: By the way - There is no need for the cast, it's a bit confusing. GC.SuppressFinalize((object)this)  => GC.SuppressFinalize(this)

Answer (score 1):

Why making an abstract class Singleton? Abstract classes were made, to be inherited by other classes. Singleton is an design pattern for avoiding static methods and keep the possibility, to make your class instanceable (Maybe for later use). You should think about your architecture.

In general you should make a class singleton in the following way:

1. Define a private constructor
2. Define a private variable: `private static readonly <<YourClass>> singleton = new <<YourClass>>()`
3. Define a public singleton property:

```
public <<YourClass>> Singleton
{
    get { return singleton; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several classic implementations of a singleton based on:

1. Static constructor initialization (Thread safe by design)
2. Instance property getter double locking for thread safety returning value.
3. .Net Lazy wrapper based property(can be configured to be thread safe, in constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Don't risk it, get it from the one who knows best: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx